# Excel VBA extract values JSON URL

Tags: json, excel, vba, google-maps, url

In Excel

I try to extract this value  "45.33887499999999"

by this **Google URL "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=bojon"** (in the example **Google URL +**"=bojon" or **+**"=VENICE%20BEACH%20CA")

with this VBA code:

```
Public Function LATITUDE(coord As String)
    Dim firstVal As String
    firstVal = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    URL = firstVal & Replace(coord, " ", "+")
    objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.send ("")
    If InStr(objHTTP.responseText, """location"" : {") = 0 Then GoTo ErrorHandl
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp"): regex.Pattern = """lat"".*?([0-9]+)": regex.Global = False
    Set matches = regex.Execute(objHTTP.responseText)
    tmpVal = Replace(matches(Index).SubMatches(0), ".", Application.International(xlListSeparator))
    LATITUDE = CDbl(tmpVal)
    Exit Function
ErrorHandl:
    LATITUDE = -1
End Function
```

but this code extracts only "45" and not "45.33887499999999"

I tried to change regex.Pattern = """lat"".*?([0-9]+)"

but I haven't found the solution

---

Finally I want to extract 3 values with 3 different formulas (created by VBA code) from this URL

**Google URL + "=bojon"**

in these rows

```
     "formatted_address" : "30010 Bojon VE, Italia",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 45.33887499999999,
           "lng" : 12.06598
```

in A1 cell: "bojon"

=GOOGDRESS(A1) result = "30010 Bojon VE, Italia"

=LATITUDE(A1) result = "45.33887499999999"

=LONGITUDE(A1) result = "12.06598"

---

another example:

**Google URL + "=VENICE%20BEACH%20CA"**

```
     "formatted_address" : "Venice Beach, California, Stati Uniti",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 33.996311,
              "lng" : -118.4561299
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 33.9636437,
              "lng" : -118.4835886
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 33.9936153,
           "lng" : -118.4799099
```

=GOOGDRESS(A1) result = "Venice Beach, California, Stati Uniti"

=LATITUDE(A1) result = "33.9936153"

=LONGITUDE(A1) result = "-118.4799099"

---

can anyone help me?

Comment: Why JSON? Why not XML https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=bojon? Much easier to parse with VBA.

Comment: You may just want to get a full json parser for VBA. There are a couple that I know of and '*shameless plug*' I wrote one myself which if you're interested, I'd be happy to share.

Answer (score 3):

Using a script control to parse the JSON and caching the json responses to avoid unnecessary XMLHTTP calls:

```
Sub Tester()

    Debug.Print GetResult("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=bojon", _
                       "results[0].geometry.location.lat")

    Debug.Print GetResult("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=bojon", _
                       "results[0].geometry.location.lng")


End Sub

Function GetResult(URL As String, jsonPath As String)

    Static responseCache As Object
    Dim objHTTP As Object, json As String
    Dim sc As Object

    If responseCache Is Nothing Then
        Set responseCache = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    End If

    If Not responseCache.exists(URL) Then
        Debug.Print "Fetching:" & URL
        Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        objHTTP.Open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=bojon", False
        objHTTP.send ("")
        json = objHTTP.responseText
        responseCache.Add URL, json
    Else
        Debug.Print "Use cache:" & URL
        json = responseCache(URL)
    End If

    Set sc = CreateObject("scriptcontrol")
    sc.Language = "JScript"
    sc.Eval "var obj=(" & json & ")" 'evaluate the json response

    GetResult = sc.Eval("obj." & jsonPath)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern: `"""lat""(\s)*:(\s)*(\d)+(.(\d)+)?"`

To break it down,

- ""lat"" matches the string
- (\s)* matches any spaces which might be in
  between the tokens
- : is literal
- (\s)* again matches spaces
- (\d)+ matches some number of digits
- (.(\d)+)? optionally matches a decimal point followed by a string of digits (at least one)

I leave the other two as an exercise to you given this example, but let me know if you have trouble!