How do I acess Excel VBA Dictionary Items with a User-defined function/ParamArray?
I have an Excel spreadsheet which creates reports based on contents of a JSON file. In the root of the object structure of the JSON is an object called "Buildings". It has two properties, "Count" and an Array of objects called "Items". One of the fields of those objects is a field called "Names". Ex:
"Buildings": {
  "Count": 2,
  "Items": [
    {
       "Name": "Building 1",
       .
       .
       .
    }
  ]
.
.
.
}

The JSON is loaded into a Dictionary called JSONDictionary using a parser I got from GitHub. I am trying to build an Excel VBA User-Defined Function which uses the JSONDictionary object to walk the nodes of the JSON structure by accepting a parameter array containing the key values in order and returns a variant containing the value of the terminal node. I have written two functions below, GetJSONValue1 and GetJSONValue2. GetJSONValue1 one works correctly but is not a very good solution for more general cases. GetJSONValue2 performs a similar function, but parses the dictionary one key at a time and is a more general approach.
Public Function GetJSONValue(ParamArray Keys() As Variant) As Variant

Dim N%

N = UBound(Keys)

Select Case N
Case 0
  GetJSONValue = JSONDictionary(Keys(0))
Case 1
  GetJSONValue = JSONDictionary(Keys(0))(Keys(1))
Case 2
  GetJSONValue = JSONDictionary(Keys(0))(Keys(1))(Keys(2))
Case 3
  GetJSONValue = JSONDictionary(Keys(0))(Keys(1))(Keys(2))(Keys(3))
Case 4
  GetJSONValue = JSONDictionary(Keys(0))(Keys(1))(Keys(2))(Keys(3))(Keys(4))
End Select

End Function


Public Function GetJSONValue2(ParamArray Keys() As Variant) As Variant

Dim I%, N%
Dim ThisDictionary As Dictionary

Set ThisDictionary = JSONDictionary
N = UBound(Keys)

For I = 0 To N - 1
  Set ThisDictionary = ThisDictionary(Keys(I))
Next I

GetJSONValue2 = ThisDictionary(Keys(N))

End Function

In the spreadsheet, the formula GetJSONValue1("Buildings","Items",1,"Name") returns "Building 1" as expected. GetJSONValue2("Buildings","Count") yields a correct result as well. But GetJSONValue2("Buildings","Items",1,"Name") returns a #VALUE error. When I step through it, the formula terminates when I try to access JSONDictionary("Items"). No exception is raised.
What am I doing wrong? TIA.

"Items" is a Collection, not a Dictionary.

Here’s a different approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/32913350/478884

I assume that you are using the JSON Converter for VBA from here: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON
This tool converts JSON-strings into data structures. A JSON is build by 2 different structures:

A list of Key-Value pairs.  Those lists are often named "objects", with key = property name and value = property value. Lot's of programming languages can create objects on the fly from a JSON but not VBA - there are no dynamic classes in VBA.
The JSON Converter creates a Dictionary out of it, you can access a property by its name (=key) to get its value.
Objects in JSON start with an {

A list of values. Those lists are often named "array". A value cannot be addresses by its name (it has no name), but by it's index.
The JSON Converter creates a Collection out of it, you can access a property by its index to get its value. (Why not an array? Because in VBA you need to dimension an array before you can store data into it. It is possible to resize it late, but that's a costly operation.)
Lists in JSON start with an [


In your structure, you have
 The root object, containing an object with 1 property Building.
  This property itself is an Object with 2 properties (Count and Items).
   Items is an array (it starts with [). Probably the property Count tells that this array contains 2 entries.
    Every entry in that array contains again an object, containing a property name.
Now all you have to do in your 2nd function is to handle the fact that you might not only have Dictionaries, but also Collections. You can do this simply by declaring Dim ThisDictionary As Object (but I would suggest to change the name):
Public Function GetJSONValue2(ParamArray Keys() As Variant) As Variant
    Dim I As long, N As Long
    Dim json As Object
    
    Set json = JSONDictionary
    N = UBound(Keys)
    
    For I = 0 To N - 1
        Debug.Print TypeName(json)
        Set json = json(Keys(I))
    Next I
    
    GetJSONValue2 = json(Keys(N))
End Function

